# module 'FBAudienceNetwork' requires feature 'objc_arc' error in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, automatic-ref-counting, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am attempting to integrate the most recent version of the FBAudienceNetwork SDK (4.12.0), and I am receiving the following error:

**module 'FBAudienceNetwork' requires feature 'objc_arc'**

My project is ARC enabled, so I am at a loss as to what is causing this error. Also, modules are enabled.

Comment: Did you try to open a new project and test it with?

Comment: Works fine in a new project

Comment: So I guess it's something with your project settings... compare between them and see what's different

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I am getting the similar errors

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen if one of the files in the project has the option "-fno-objc-arc". The resolution is to search and clear and reset this option in your project.